# AWS Websockets errors during message sending

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have ± 300 connections from the mobile apps connected to AWS websocket server.
Socket connection is used to broadcast chat messages and other internal messages, so it's pretty loaded.
I am using NodeJS and AWS ManagementAPI to broadcast messages to all clients as fast as i can. Code looks like this(example):

```
// Gather all connection ID's in the array of async calls
const postCalls = connectionIDs.map(async (connection_id) => {
    await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ConnectionId: connection_id, Data: 
    postData}).promise().catch((e) => {
                        
        if (e.statusCode === 410) {
            return drop_connection(connection_id);
        } 
    })
})

// And send it 
try {
    await Promise.allSettled(postCalls);
} catch (e) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: e.stack };
}
```

It works well for 90% of time but sometimes when we have peak of online users it starting to fail with these errors:

1. Sometimes it's

```
InternalServerErrorException: Endpoint request timed out
    at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12) {
  code: 'InternalServerErrorException',
  time: 2020-11-17T05:57:37.184Z,
  requestId: '5fa1f388-191c-4990-97a6-e98a0c0a869e',
  statusCode: 504,
  retryable: true
}
```

2. Or simple 'TimeoutError'

I figured out that if i will not drop these connections after error, i will receive `Limit Exceeded Exception   429` error.

How to deal with it? Why timeouts happening so often? This thing impacts whole system and a lot of clients saying that they are just dropped from the app ( Because i am dropping connection on any error).
I did not found any documentation about these errors or how to handle/prevent them.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?